# Need help for writing Junit test for IF condition

Tags: java, junit

I'm looking for help to write a Junit test for the below mentioned method. I want to cover the `if` condition in `getBooleanValue()` method.

```
package app;

public class IfConditionTesting {
    public static final String BOOLEAN_VALUE = "booleanvalue";

    public static boolean getBooleanValue(){
        boolean myReturn = false;
        if(BOOLEAN_VALUE.equalsIgnoreCase("booleanvalue")){
            myReturn = true;
        }
        return myReturn;

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the contract of `getBooleanValue()`?

Comment: Hi Pal, welcome to StackOverflow! We typically expect some sort of effort to be put forth in solving your problem before we help. A great way you can do this for this question is to include your current test case that you've attempted to write for this method.

Comment: in current state, it will always return true. you compare BOOLEAN_VALUE to hardcoded string, same value. no matter what it will return true. you may as well repleace implementation with return true;. and such functions does not require tests.

Comment: i tried as:
@Test
public void testGetBooleanValue(){
IfConditionTesting obj = new IfConditionTesting();
assertTrue(true, obj.getBooleanValue());
} but i did a mistake while explaining the question itself as the "if" condition i have written will not directly compare the constant "booleanvalue" string, it will be other method call from other class...
if(BOOLEAN_VALUE.equalsIgnoreCase("other method call from other class, which might return "booleanvalue" or some other value"))

Comment: So, my question is, can i be able to write test case for only covering that "if" condition?. or it is not required? But how can I find out that the if condition is getting failed.. Please let me know for any further information

Comment: @Pal please edit that code into your original question. It is really hard to look at code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple:

```
@Test
public void testResultIsFalse() {
  assertThat(IfConditionTesting.getBooleanValue(), is(true));
}
```

That is all there is. As of now, your method will **always** return true.

But to cover your question: the point is - you want to write at least ONE testcase for each path that can be **possibly** taken in your method.

In this method, there is only ONE path; which will result in having the method return true. So that one test above covers that.

Of course, your production code doesn't make any sense. Consider

```
 public static boolean isSameAsConstant(String boolAsString){
    boolean myReturn = false;
    if(BOOLEAN_VALUE.equalsIgnoreCase(boolAsString)){
        myReturn = true;
    }
    return myReturn; 
 }
```

Now you could start writing *multiple* testcases, as you have a mean to *control* from the outside what will happen within your code (by providing **different** strings in each test).

Comment: Thank you very much for quick response and it has cleared my doubt from one part of my question. And really Thanks again for the same. It is helpful for me.

Comment: @Cache Staheli  Yes, it will be good if i can put the real code for which i am trying to write JUnit to explain the question what exactly I want. I might not be able to explain the question properly, which I am looking for

Again Thank you all for the assistance and quick response...